# Web driver : Calendar year Xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am facing problem while creating XPath / CSS selector for the calendar component.

I want XPath/CSS with the string passed in XPath.

For Ex ::

//div.yearvalue[contains(.,'1994')]

I tried with the above XPath but it didn't work for me. PFA Screenshot[image]

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//div.yearvalue[contains(.,'1994')]` is not acceptable XPath syntax. What you need is

```
//div[@class='yearvalue' and .='1994']
```